# ¿Cómo puedo cortar una cadena de 12 enteros en grupos de 2 dígitos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, split, string

Ej: Tengo esta cadena `'144440261218'` y necesito cortarla en seis pedazos:

```
a: 14
b: 44
c: 40
d: 26
e: 12
f: 18
```

Intenté hacerlo con una expresión regular utilizando, de la siguiente manera

```
import re
s = 144440261218
s_split = re.split(r'[\d]{2}', s)
```

Pero la respuesta es una lista de 7 cadenas vacias:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Hola en lugar de expresion regular, deberias mirar con replace o str.replace, python no contrlo muy bien pero en cuanto a languajes de programacion son similares todos jaja

Answer (score 5):

No es necesario usar `split`. Puedes hacerlo usando `findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> num = '144440261218'
>>> re.findall('([\d+]{2})', num)
['14', '44', '40', '26', '12', '18']
```

---

Otra forma usando una lista por comprensión:

```
>>> num = '144440261218'
>>> [num[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(num), 2)]
['14', '44', '40', '26', '12', '18']
```

El `range()` no es más que la forma de usar el índice de tu cadena de números:

```
>>> list(range(0, len(num), 2)) # Los índices
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Luego se toman los números agrupados de a 2 usando `num[x:x+2]`.

Comment: Creo que la expresión regular podría ser simplemente "\d{2}".

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias usar recursividad algo como esto donde recibo el numero y cada cuantos digitos deseas separarlos:

```
def split(s, n):
    if len(s) < n:
        return []
    else:
        return [s[:n]] + split(s[n:], n)

print(split('144440261218', 2))
```

el posible resultado es algo como esto:
[image: result_python]
espero te sirva y puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades !!

Answer (score 1):

Presento otra alternativa que no se ha comentado.

`split` lo que hace es dividir en función de la expresión regular que le pasas como entrada y deja el resto. Como toda tu entrada son 12 números y divides en grupos de dos, el resto son 6 trozos de 'nada'.

En realidad, no ibas mal encaminado. Te faltó añadir paréntesis a tu expresión regular. Con `split`, cuando la expresión regular utiliza paréntesis, se devuelve además lo que haya dentro, aunque esto se haya utilizado para dividir.

```
import re
s = '144440261218'
s_split = filter(bool, re.split(r'(\d{2})', s))
```

También es necesario filtrar la lista porque ahora se devolverán tanto los números como los espacios vacíos entre ellos. Con un simple filtro en base a que evalue a booleano, descartaremos los espacios vacíos.

Otro cambio es que `[\d]{2}` y `\d{2}` es lo mismo, así que he utilizado ésto último ya que es algo más simple.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa más, que no requiere expresiones regulares y que está parametrizada para que sea posible agrupar los elementos de 2 en 2, o 3 en 3, o como se desee. Funciona también para listas.

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)
```

Esta función recibe como primer parámetro un iterable (puede ser una lista, una cadena, una tupla) y un entero `n`. Devuelve otro iterable en el que, cada vez que se itera por él, se obtiene una tupla con `n` elementos del iterable que recibió como parámetro. Si el iterable de entrada no tenía un múltiplo de `n` elementos, los que sobran se descartan.

Por ejemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
for p in grouper(lista, 2):
  print(p)
```

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
```

También funciona sobre cadenas, pero lo que devuelve son tuplas de letras:

```
cadena = "12345"
for p in grouper(cadena, 2):
  print(p)
```

```
('1', '2')
('3', '4')
```

Puedes usar `str.join()` sobre estos resultados para obtener cadenas de dos dígitos. Ejemplo:

```
cadena = "144440261218"
trozos = ["".join(g) for g in grouper(cadena, 2)]
```

Y en `trozos` obtendrás la lista:

```
['14', '44', '40', '26', '12', '18']
```