# ¿Partir una cadena de tres en tres y agregarlo a una lista?

Tags: python

¿Es posible a partir de una cadena del estilo `'agtgccacgtag'` obtener una lista como la siguiente: `['agt','gcc','acg','tag']`?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estudiante, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Aunque tu pregunta es buena, es demasiado amplia. Considera [edit] tu publicacion y agregar un [mcve] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve [esta respuesta que di](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226265/7123) a una pregunta similar

Answer (score 2):

Una solución bastante eficiente usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(".{1,3}")

dna = "agtgccacgtag"    
ksplits = pat.findall(dna)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta function `grouper()` es [de la documentación para `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html). Cuando le das un "iterable" (como una lista) la funcion te da un "iterator" nuevo que emite bloques de longitud `n` a partir del original. Para la entrada de tu pregunta, lo usarías así:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Agrupar los datos en bloques de tamaño fijo"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

dna = 'agtgccacgtag'

bloques = ["".join(b) for b in grouper(dna, 3)]

print(bloques)    # ['agt', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tag']
```

Ya que la funcion `grouper()` espera una lista como argumento, cuando le pasas una cadena es tratada como una lista de caracteres.

Comment: La respuesta me parece perfecta (+1) pero contiene algunos errores gramaticales del uso del español. Si te parece bien, puedo editar la respuesta para corregirlos, para que sea más fácil de leer (a la vez que te ayudo a mejorar tu español) :-)

Comment: Gracias, y por favor cambia cualquier quieres! Estoy aqui en gran parte para mejorar mi español :)

Answer (score 1):

con list comprehension en una linea:

```
s = 'agtgccacgtag'
print([s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un `for` de una manera limpia y rápida

```
lista=[]
a='agtgccacgtag'
for i in range(3,len(a)+1,3): lista.append(a[i-3:i])
```